# Laravel artisan route:cache throw error Constant XXX already defined

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, laravel-artisan

## Env

- Laravel 5.5

## Issue

When I run:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

It throws error:

> In app.php line 3:
>
> Constant XXX already defined

in my config/app.php, I defined some global constants, such as:

```
define("XXX", "xxx");
```

If I removed them, no error thrown anymore.

## Question

I wonder if I want to keep those constants in config files, is there any way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do this in such way. If you want to add any new item in `config/app.php`, just try this way:

1. in `config/app.php` file, Add `'XXX' => 'xxx'`.

2.When you want to call this variable, use it `config('app.XXX')`

Answer (score 0):

With Laravel 5.7, I clear configuration cache and route cache, it's work for me:

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score -1):

For Constant,

You can create constants.php in app or in config directory. You can define your constant there,

```
define('XXX', 'xxx');
```

And you use it same like constant.

```
e.g echo XXX;
```